# Functions not working on new pages asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a project and the strangest thing is happening.  I have been trying to figure it out for multiple hours.  The issue is if I create a new web form, the code behind will see all the controls, but from the .aspx page I can use any public functions from the code behind.  For example if I create the following function:

```
    Public Function Hey()
    Return True
End Function
```

Then I go to the .aspx source and put the following:

```
<%# hey%>
```

I get the following error: Error    2   'hey' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

The following is WebForm5.aspx:

```
      <%@ Page Title="Web Form" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm5.aspx.vb" Inherits="InventoryManagement.WebForm5" Async="true" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%# hey%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm5.aspx.vb:

```
Public Class WebForm5
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
    Public Function Hey()
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

I have "older" pages that I can call the exact same function from code behind. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this issue has been a problem for the last 3+ hours.  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was to clean and rebuild project.  This solved the issue right away!